# How to include classes in a deployment package of MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, hosting

I have prepared a web deployment package from my staging environment as a FileSystem. However, there is not a folder with necessary classes. My logic of hitcounter is situated there. I have tried to just copy this folder with classes to a web deployment folder, but I've caught an error when I try to run my website at a hosting provider. If I run locally my web application it works okay.

Is there a special way to include this folder to a web deployment package?

I run on a restricted shared hosting (godaddy).

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also the package you have created, was that built using VS publish, or an msbuild script, or have you exported the package from IIS?

Comment: the classes are compiled into an assembly in the BIN folder. they don't get published to the web server, perhaps you are missing a dll file in you bin folder for hitcounter?

Comment: @brent mannering, I use VS Publish. The error is "Application /n error", just a general message of an error. I do not copy files to IIS Server, I just run on my local mashine by VS 2010.

Comment: @MattTabor, how can I know whether my hit counter.cs file is made to dll file. I've seen to bin folder and haven't found dll files with "hitcounter" name. How to make a class to dll library?

Comment: There should be a dll with the name of your namespace.

Comment: @PrerakK, I do not have such dll's. How to make own dll's from my class files?

Comment: They are compiled when you publish your project, they should be in the bin folder. are you publishing using "File System" using an empty directory?

Comment: @MattTabor, yeah, I do. However, I've just seen the reference libraries. I do not see the files with name like "hitcounter"

Comment: if your hitcounter class is inside your project namespace it will be compiled inside your project dll. so if your namespace is like myproject.helpers.hitcounter, then it will be in the myproject.dll

Comment: @MattTabor, ok, yes I have a such library. I thought if there is a folder with Views, then it should be a folder with my created classes. Write your answer and I mark as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your hitcounter class is inside your project namespace it will be compiled inside your project dll. so if your namespace is like myproject.helpers.hitcounter, then it will be in the myproject.dll

there is no need to add the classes to your hosting service.